# web application can't connect to database

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ubuntu-10.04, jdbc

I have a web application which accesses MySQL using Hibernate as a JPA provider.  Though all is well on my development rig, once I deploy the WAR to my server I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
```

The dev machine runs Ubuntu 10.10 and the server 10.04; both are using the provided MySQL package and Apache's (not Ubuntu's) tomcat6.  I have more than triple-checked that the database is running, the credentials are correct and the driver is available.

I have this Resource definition in tomcat's context.xml:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/phenome_repository"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="correctUserName"
    password="correctPassword"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/correctDatabaseName"    
/>
```

Since the web application works locally, I believe its configuration to be correct (it has a resource-ref in its web.xml).  As for MySQL, it is configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 and the "correctUser" above has all the necessary privileges (on localhost *and* 127.0.0.1).

Does anyone know any less usual causes of "Cannot open connection"?

[Full stacktrace](http://tintin.sfsu.edu/software/stacktrace.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turns out another admin had denied `ALL: ALL` in `hosts.deny` and `hosts.allow` was empty.  Placing `mysqld: 127.0.0.1` in `hosts.allow` fixed the problem.

For reference, here are all the potential causes of errors like the one I described:

- localhost may not connect as per `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny`
- JDBC driver is not available to tomcat
- The database is configured to disallow network connections
- The database is not running

In each of these cases the full stacktrace will be subtly different.  A missing driver will be more apparent in the stacktrace than the other causes listed here.

Please suggest any items missing from the above list.